Notepad++ Combining two types of lines (similar information) throughout a large document?
So, I have chat logs between a friend and I from Snapchat that we want in an easier to read way. You get the data in an html format from Snapchat, and so far I've got it edited down to this format:
2022-03-02 10:01:41 UTC
[insert chat message here blah blah blah]
Friend

2022-03-02 10:01:41 UTC
[insert chat message here blah blah blip bloop]
Me

I've had to do tons of find and replacing, deleting, reversed order, and so on to get it to that point. The plan as it stands is importing the file into Apple Pages to both preserve Emojis and have a cloud file to view together. I want to make it as easy to read and on the eyes as possible.
Is there a way to take every line that has the time (2022-03-02 10:01:41 UTC) and move it down to Join, or move just below lines that say "Friend" or "Me". So it would look something like:
[insert chat message here blah blah blah]
Friend 2022-03-02 10:01:41 UTC

[OR]

[insert chat message here blah blah blip bloop]
Me
2022-03-02 10:01:41 UTC

Or, the doing the reverse:
Friend 2022-03-02 10:01:41 UTC
[insert chat message here blah blah blah]

[OR]
2022-03-02 10:01:41 UTC
Me
[insert chat message here blah blah blip bloop]


Or, something like this, effectively just flipping the Time lines and the Name lines, which I think I like the idea of most:
Friend
[insert chat message here blah blah blah]
2022-03-02 10:01:41 UTC

Me
[insert chat message here blah blah blip bloop]
2022-03-02 10:01:41 UTC

I have other questions that I know for sure surpass Notepad++'s potential capabilities, such as formatting the text: Italicizing and reducing font size of every line with the Time, applying color and increasing font size of every Name line.
I've tried Line Operations with moving lines up/down, but that would take way too long to be feasible. I've also tried various Find options (like selecting all lines with our Name) and then doing the Line Operation, but that didn't work either. I'm wanting to do every line, at the same time.

I suggest writing a program to do this. Read the input file and write a new file that contains the input that you read but formatted the way you want.

This is something you can do with regex, specifically by building groups. In Notepad++, in the replace window, check Regular expression and . matches new line. Then replace
(^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d.*?UTC)\r\n(.*?)^(Me|Friend)

with
$2$3 $1


Thanks so much for the answer! I'm not familiar with programming or regex much at all. Is it as simple as how you put it? Or is there a tutorial you could point me towards to learn exactly how to apply this? Or, is the link you provided enough for that?

Regex in itself is not as hard to learn as a full programming language. You don't have to know all of it to be able to use some simple expressions. There are different implementations though that differ on some points. The link I provided is a good starting point. I find sites like regex101 very useful too.

Also please consider accepting the answer if your problem is solved.

Thanks so much! I did manage to use what you provided (along with learning a bit about what each "term," for lack of a better understanding and word on my part, you used in what you gave me) to play around with and got a solution! It was pretty fun and interesting learning, too, so thanks! And thanks for asking me to accept the answer as well, since I'm new here :)
